# Passing a second parameter to batch process

Tags: apex, batch

I have the following block of code that is working.  However, I need to pass an additional field that will be used in the FINISH block to save a custom metadata value for the next time the process runs.  Please bear with me as I'm pretty new to Apex and OOP.  BTW - The second parameter is a DateTime variable and I already have the code to update a custom metadata value.  I just need to see how to alter the call/input to pass a datetime value to the finish block.  Thanks!

```
public class HRM_ProcessAccountFromList_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> 
{

public List<Account> lstAccounts = new List<Account>();

public HRM_ProcessAccountFromList_Batch(List<Account> lstSentToBatch){
    lstAccounts = lstSentToBatch;
}   

public List<Account> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return lstAccounts;
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){  
    List<Account> lstAccsUpdate = new List<Account>();      // a list to hold existing records
    List<Account> lstAccsInsert = new List<Account>();      // a list to hold new records

    for (Account a: scope){
        if (String.isBlank(a.ID)) {
            lstAccsInsert.add(a);
        } else {
            lstAccsUpdate.add(a);
        }
    }
    if (lstAccsInsert.size() > 0) INSERT lstAccsInsert;
    if (lstAccsUpdate.size() > 0) UPDATE lstAccsUpdate;        
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.FINEST, '!!! HRM_ProcessAccountFromList_Batch Completed');
}
```

Comment: You can't update `Custom Metadata` from Apex. At least, not natively. Also, no need to check if lists are empty before doing DML on them.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I used the information on the following link - https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/03/02/create-update-custom-metadata-using-apex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a second constructor, or modify the existing one:

```
DateTime whateverYouWantToCallThis;
public HRM_ProcessAccountFromList_Batch(List<Account> lstSentToBatch, DateTime finishDateTimeValue){
    lstAccounts = lstSentToBatch;
    whateverYouWantToCallThis = finishDateTimeValue;
}
```

Any values that are stored before Database.executeBatch is called will be preserved all the way through the finish method.

Side Note: Your execute method can be reduced to simply:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){  
   upsert scope Account.Id;
}
```

This avoids the need to split in to insert/update lists.

Comment: Do you actually need to sort if there is no mixing of object types?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Every time you go from having an Id to not (i.e. switching from update to insert) or vice versa, or reach 200 records, you consume a DML "chunk". You're only allowed 10 chunks this way. Sorting should put all the new records next to each other, and all the existing records next to each other. Or... at least, that's how I remember it. I could be wrong?

Comment: We were trying to optimize performance and the UPSERT has more overhead than separate update and insert statements based on our testing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Nevermind, just tested it, the sort doesn't matter.

Comment: @mwolf00 The difference in performance shouldn't matter? You may have been seeing differences simply because each transaction's speed depends on debug settings and server load.

Comment: Basically, my architect told me he wanted them separated so that's what he got.  It's only a few lines of code extra to keep him happy so everyone's happy!

Comment: @mwolf00 fair enough. Still, you don't need the `if(!list.isempty())` part--that's a carry over from years ago when every DML statement automatically used a governor limit. And if you need to argue performance, *not* checking first is faster :p

Comment: @sfdcfox - I'm not sure I understand.  I don't have that line of code.  Thanks for your patience and assistance.

Comment: @mwolf00 e.g. `if (lstAccsInsert.size() > 0) INSERT lstAccsInsert;`, the if is not necessary here.